# How can I voluntarily lose ranking score in Starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

I am a bronze league player, but the last 20 games I have faced opponents a lot more skilful than me.

I tried leaving the league and playing new placement matches. I was placed in the Bronze league again, although I really tried hard in those placement matches. That proves I am on a bronce skill, I think. But I still only get silver league opponents or higher although I have 0 points in the league.

How can I lose ranking score?

Or how many games do I have to bear loosing until the MMR (Matchmaking rating) decides that I am not fit for silver?

Comment: You lose ranking score when you lose a match. If that's what you mean

Comment: Hi rubo77, losing can be frustrating. Sounds like you are on a bad losing streak. I'm sure you are improving with every game though. Keep fighting!

Comment: I just wondered, if i also loose rank by surrendering immediately. There could be a minimum time you hae to play so the game counts

Comment: @rubo77 a loss is a loss, the game does not concider how long the game was. So you shouldent worry about that.

Comment: Why would you want to face easier players? Playing against harder plyers will force you to learn new tactics and methods of playing the game; thus, making you better. Just have fun!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are matched against other players based on your MMR (Matchmaking rating). 
If you win one game, your MMR should theoretically rise — and vice versa.

Bronze league is the lowest league you can get into.
So you leaving the league wouldn't aid you that much.

The fact that you face players from a Silver league indicates that your MMR is trying to determine whether you are fit for Silver or not. If you keep losing to the Silver players, you will be matched against Bronze players again.

The only way you can lose ranking scores is by losing games.

The MMR is based on a normal distribution, so it should only match you against players matching your own MMR.

You can lose on purpose, and lower your own MMR. I wouldn't recommend this though. As you play against better players, you should become better yourself.
Always watch your replays.

Answer (score -1):

As playing in the league is only about winning and climbing up the ladder, it is like it is: you have to play against a lot of silver players until your skill matches them or you loose enough games against them so the AI decides, that you are not fit for silver and you will automatically be matched against bronze players again.

If you are only playing for practice, you can either play against the AI computers or if you prefer real players as opponent you should **invite players to a party** once you found someone, that is at the same level of skill as you, and start a **custom game** with them.

Answer (score -2):

If you start a game and see, you play against a silver or more, you can say sorry and surrender immediately. (Be aware, that this could annoy some people though)

(You can distinguish the enemies in the loading screen with the map, cause they have a silver border around their portrait unranked players are blue, see [this thread](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=395674))

After loosing 20 times against silver opponents before, I **surrendered only three games**, and it seems my **internal MMR** (Matchmaking rating) is lowered enough, so I got bronce opponents again.

It is a pitty that you have to annoy some opponentsto loose ranking by immediately ssurrendering, but it seems to be the only way, cause leaving league and playing new placement matches doesent change your internal MMR.

Comment: Unranked players does not have border around their portrait. Blue borders are diamond players.

Comment: yes, they are: unranked players are blue. Diamond is a kind of blue also, but more shiny. I added a link to a thread with all colors to my answer

Comment: Well if you put it that, yes its blue hehe :)

Comment: If you are not playing to win, you shouldn't be playing league. Your just outright surrendering does to them what is annoying you: You push your opponents' rankings up whether that would be the outcome or not, potentially getting them exactly into the same predicament. As you mentioned, many players, including myself, find this annoying. Also, this is frowned upon by Blizzard (one of the reasons you can only have one account unlike say in WCIII), especially if done overly in order to pick on weaker opponents. I therefore find this not to be the correct answer.

Comment: You are right, I should have been a bit more patient and wait until the the MMR is finished trying to determine whether you are fit for Silver or not. It took only 3 more games.

Comment: I will leave this answer here for completeness, cause I guess many players with my problem will come to this as a thought too.